# Auth0 Lock Component not showing in React with container option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

(Using React) I have a `/login` route and a `/signup` route to display `Login` and `SignUp` components. In my `Login` component I'm using [Auth0's Lock component](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10) to display a login form and I'm also using the [`container` configuration option](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#container-string-)  for the form to be displayed in my own `div` rather than as the default modal.

When my `Login` component loads for the first time (or after a refresh of the `/login` route) the Auth0 Lock component loads correctly. **My problem is when I navigate from the `/login` route to the `/signup` route and then back to the `/login` route and the Auth0 Lock component does not load at all.** When inspecting the page I can see that my `container` `div` is empty.

I've found [this issue on Auth0's github](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular/issues/119) of others running into the same problem using Angular, but their solution is to set `auth.config.auth0lib.$container` to `null` which doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking through the [auth0 Lock source](https://github.com/auth0/lock/blob/bb92858006eb1b39e38a9fb9000704554dc69997/src/core.js) I found the `hide` method which has solved my problem:

```
hide() {
  closeLock(this.id, true);
}
```

In my `Login` component I override the [`componentWillUnmount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) method, get a reference to the `Auth0Lock`, and call `hide()`:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.lock.hide();
}
```

Now when I navigate away from my `Login` component at `/login` to another route and then back to `/login` the Auth0 Lock component reloads and displays correctly.